# Oracle - Finding Max (date) when column could have null values and NULL is the max date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, max

I have a table with a date column that has date values and nulls too. Nulls represent open-ended date and hence it is the max date.
How can I find the row with max date using sql

If Null exists, that record is the max date. If no nulls then the row with the max date needs to be returned

Comment: "The row" (note the use of singular, not plural) implies that there will be only **one** row with the maximum date. Is the "maximum date" guaranteed to be unique? If not, then the question itself is ambiguous - you must explain what you need to return in the case of ties for "maximum" date (regardless of whether it's `null` or not).

Comment: you are right. There could be multiple. But I want to find the rows that has NULL or MAX Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use an analytic function like `row_number` in a subquery.

Something like this:

**Sample data**

```
create table t (id number, expiry date);

insert into t (id, expiry) values (3, sysdate);
insert into t (id, expiry) values (8, null);
```

**Relevant subquery**

```
select id, expiry, row_number() over (order by expiry desc) as rn
from   t;

        ID EXPIRY                          RN
---------- ----------------------- ----------
         8                                  1
         3 01.03.2022 20:27:45              2
```

Note that `order by ... desc` by default includes the option `nulls first` - so this does exactly what you need.

In the outer query, you just need to select `where rn = 1`:

```
select id, expiry
from   (
         select id, expiry, row_number() over (order by expiry desc) as rn
         from   t
       )
where  rn = 1;

        ID EXPIRY                 
---------- -----------------------
         8
```

I asked for clarification regarding "ties". If they are possible in your data, you must clarify the desired handling. For example, if you must return all rows with the "latest date", then you should use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`. For example:

Add one more row to the table

```
insert into t (id, expiry) values (9, null);
```

Modified query:

```
select id, expiry
from   (
         select id, expiry, rank() over (order by expiry desc) as rn
         from   t
       )
where  rn = 1;

        ID EXPIRY                 
---------- -----------------------
         8                        
         9
```

Note that the Oracle optimizer is smart in such queries - it will not, in fact, perform a full ordering of all rows by date. The plan will include a `window sort pushed rank` operation, which does just the minimum work needed to find the rows where the rank (or row number) is 1; it doesn't fully order all rows by the ordering column (`expiry` in my examples).

Comment: Or syntactic sugar "order by expiry desc fetch first 1 row with ties" which does internally the same (adds analytic functions with predicates)

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - with the distinction that `fetch first` requires Oracle 12 or higher; analytic functions were introduced much earlier. People shouldn't be on versions older than 12, but a significant number are.

Comment: Agreed with all! My comment was just to expand it a bit, so people could use more modern features if they use so expensive and powerful rdbms. Unfortunately, I see a lot of people who do not know new features